# Showing (a +b)^2= a^2 +b^2 of commutative ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $\mathrm{char}(R)=2$. Let $a,b$ element of $R$. Show that $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2$ and $(a×b)^2=a^2 × b^2$.

I do know how to show the two proves but I'm not sure what to do with the $\mathrm{char}(R)= 2$
could I please be assisted here.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint 1.**

$$(a+b)^{2} = a^{2} + ab + ba + b^{2}$$

What does commutativity imply about middle?

**Hint 2.** Writte

$$(ab)^2 = (ab)(ab)$$

Comment: The $\operatorname{Char} 2$ criterion is used in the first step. Think about how this fails to hold in, say, $\mathbb{Z}$.